# Alternativas ao uso de transações no MyISAM

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, transações

Tenho uma aplicação que se encontra numa hospedagem que não me dá suporte ao mecanismo de armazenamento InnoDB, logo, fico a mercê do uso de MyISAM.

Existe uma alternativa segura ao uso de transações numa base de dados com o tipo de mecanismo MyISAM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De forma geral não tem. Você pode fazer um mecanismo complexo na aplicação para tentar simular isto, mas é extremamente difícil fazer certo, dá muito trabalho, terá uma enorme perda de performance e um problema até maior na mão.

Tem uma solução simples: troque de hospedagem.

Antes pense se realmente precisa das transações. Nem sempre ela é tão necessária assim, o uso sem não é tão trágico quanto dizem, só não é 100%.

Ou mude para o SQLite que tem transações, é mais simples e performático (só não sei se resolve tudo o que precisa).